# Posting XML SOAP Envelope on Lazarus

Tags: post, soap, soap-client, lazarus

I'm struggling with application "client side" to communicate with service.
Requirement for that type of communication is to use XML Soap Envelope.

I'm trying to use TFPHTTPClient for that. I prepare Form to see response from serwer but something is missing.
When I send a request I receive error "Stream read error"
On Form I put Button and Memo1 for displaing XML code and Memo2 for answear.
Interesting is when I copy code from memo1 and paste into SoapUI everything is OK
My code is:

```
    procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
        var
          FPHTTPClient: TFPHTTPClient;
          SL: TStringList;
          Str: String;
     
        begin
          FPHTTPClient := TFPHTTPClient.Create(nil);
          try
            FPHTTPClient.AllowRedirect := True;
            FPHTTPClient.KeepConnection:=True;
            FPHTTPClient.AddHeader('Content-Type','application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8');
            FPHTTPClient.AddHeader('User-Agent','Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.1)');
     
     
            SL := TStringList.Create;
     
            try
              SL.Add('<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns="http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07"> ');
              SL.Add('<soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">');
              SL.Add('<wsa:To>https://wyszukiwarkaregontest.stat.gov.pl/wsBIR/UslugaBIRzewnPubl.svc</wsa:To>');
              SL.Add('<wsa:Action>http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07/IUslugaBIRzewnPubl/Zaloguj</wsa:Action>');
              SL.Add('</soap:Header>');
              SL.Add('<soap:Body>');
              SL.Add('<ns:Zaloguj>');
              SL.Add('<ns:pKluczUzytkownika>abcde12345abcde12345</ns:pKluczUzytkownika>');
              SL.Add('</ns:Zaloguj>');
              SL.Add('</soap:Body>');
              SL.Add('</soap:Envelope>');
     
     
     
        Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
        Memo1.Lines := SL;
        Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
              try
     
                Str:=FPHTTPClient.FormPost('https://wyszukiwarkaregontest.stat.gov.pl/wsBIR/UslugaBIRzewnPubl.svc',SL);
                            //ShowMessage(Str);
     
        Memo2.text := Str;
     
              except
                on E: exception do
                  ShowMessage(E.Message);
              end;
            finally
              SL.Free;
            end;
          finally
            FPHTTPClient.Free;
          end;
        end;
```

Answer (score -1):

-- Memo1.Lines := SL;
++ Memo1.Lines.Assign(SL);

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer and add some context.

Comment: Please try for [answer]. Using appropriate formatting might also help a little. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help And please consider taking the [tour].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).